# zooming out a webpage in css/javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, scale

So the problem started when I tested my website on a windows with 150% scale, its elements were bigger than what I wanted as I built it on a windows with 125% scale.
I figured that changing the scale in this windows to 125% solves the problem, also zooming out in the webpage does, while searching for css/javascript solution I found few threads here suggesting solutions that I tried, such as:

1. `document.querySelector("meta[name=viewport]").setAttribute('content', 'width=device-width, initial-scale='+(1/window.devicePixelRatio));`
   doesn't have any effect on desktop, only on mobile.
2. `body { zoom: 0.8; }`

   this is the closest solution to the actual zooming result, but still not the same as sections that had `height: 100vh` now has something like 80vh, width is good but still not 100% equivilant to zooming out and hitting 80% zoom level.
3. `html { transform: scale(.8); transform-origin: 0 0; }`
   that keeps a white marginal areas on the right, so I tried to add:
   `width: 125%; height: 125%;`
   but that still isn't equivilant, it has the same effect of previous solution.

Comment: @mplungjan could you please explain what do you mean by that?

Comment: Please post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: @mplungjan let's start with the fact that it's not an X/Y problem, I stated very clearly in the beginning of the question about the problem I'm encountering.
Second, unfortunatelly I can't post "minimal reproducible example", as I said in the post, some windows has 150% scale and the majority has 100%-125%, the result you'll get from the code is very dependant on your windows configurations of the display.
Again, my problem is very clear and what I need is very clear, it's a known problem in windows.

Comment: Good luck. Without images and code it is impossible to answer as you can see from the lack of answers